# Partitioning a disk with already existing partitions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, fdisk

On a Linux Virtual Machine that I recently setup, I had a disk (`/dev/sdb`) of size 20G in which I created 8 partitions (3 primary, 1 extended containing 5 logical partitions), using up to 10G of space. So there's 10G unpartitioned.

I can't use `fdisk` as the maximum allowable partitions 4 already created. Is there any other way to create new partitions on the remaining 10G space, without modifying or deleting existing partitions?

I could add a new disk `/dev/sdc` and use it, but I want to see what else can be done on /dev/sdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before attempting to create a new partition, you have to grow the existing extended partition to fill the whole space and then create a new logical partition inside the extended partition.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use fdisk to add an extended partition with no trouble. I've done so a number of times in Ubuntu as well as in several other ancient distros. But I prefer the graphical program GParted. It's available as a live CD if you don't have X installed.

Comment: Actually i couldn't, it says 'No free sectors available'. It would have been possible if i had atleast one spare primary partition, but i've used all 4 of them already

Comment: In that case,  you're doing something wrong. The fact that you're up to the limit tells me that you're still trying to create a primary partition instead of a logical one.

Comment: $fdisk /dev/sdb
| Then,
command (m for help): n | 
No free sectors available | 

I need to type 'n' followed by 'p' or 'l' to create a primary or logical partition right? Can't get there.

Comment: Are you sure that you have free space on the disk? If `fdisk` can't do it, then it probably can't be done. I suspect that there's a misconfiguration somewhere. Please post the results of a session, including printing the partition table. Alternatively, try GParted. It's *much* easier than `fdisk`. I used `fdisk` a lot back in the day, but I now use GParted nearly exclusively. It's that much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Extended partition take one logical partition by itself, It's why it is called extent, it take one logical and permit to repartition it's content.

My advice would be to swapoff, delete swap. Resize root to take place of the swap, then create your extended partition, at the end of it, create your new swap. It doesn't matter if it is on extent.

Modify your fstab accordingly and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gdisk to convert the Virtual Hard Drive to GPT. GPT allows a virtually unlimited amount of partions. gdisk operates just like fdisk, but has more options. Install Gdisk (With Ubuntu/Debian use apt-get install gdisk), then run it. (`gdisk /dev/sda`)

Replace sda with your hard drive then just browse the help menus, they are pretty simple.